# JPA Annotation/Metadata mapping for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I am trying to finish the modeling for an application that I plan to deploy on google app engine.

I have a base class, Account that is abstract, annotated as follows:

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Account {

    @Id
    private Key id;
    .....
```

I then have 2 concrete classes, AdministratorAccount:

```
@Entity
public class AdministratorAccount extends Account {
```

and CustomerAccount:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerAccount extends Account {
```

I also have all 3 declared in my persistence.xml file.

When I try to persist a CustomerAccount, I get a 500 error:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NoPersistenceInformationException: The class "com.nucleus.entitymodel.Account" is required to be persistable yet no Meta-Data/Annotations can be found for this class. Please check that the Meta-Data/annotations is defined in a valid file location.
```

Any ideas on what the problem may be? I tried to follow the documentation on the GAE site for JPA inheritance.

Comment: No class should have Entity AND MappedSuperclass ever. The log would tell you what class is known about. You're also using ancient software.

Comment: what software am I using that is ancient? Also, I got the example from the google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview

Comment: If you look at the Worker.java example, it clearly has mappedsuperclass and entity annotations.

Comment: Your example is WRONG! Read the JPA spec if you don't believe me. The versions of DataNucleus used by "Google JPA" are v3 or earlier, i.e unsupported and ancient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note Google's [warning](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview) about JPA, consider moving to Objectify or their low level datastore.

What your warning says it that your JPA entity classes are not enhanced.
Google´s datastore runs on [datanucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/enhancer.html) and requires the classes to be enhanced for persistence.
This can be done using a maven plugin e.g.;

```
        <plugins>
        <!-- This plug-in "enhances" your domain model objects (i.e. makes them persistent for datanucleus) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>false</fork>
                <!-- Make sure this path contains your persistent classes! -->
                <mappingIncludes>**/model/*.class</mappingIncludes>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                <api>JPA</api>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- force maven-datanucleus-plugin to use the same version of datanucleus-core -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```